# How do I use PHP to make use of my HTML code

Tags: php, html, button

I am doing an assignment for Uni. It requires me to make an HTML form that needs a user to input what their name is, what table number they're sitting on, if they're a regular customer, and their actual coffee order.

I have done this so far, but now I'm asked in the assignment to create a PHP file to make use of this information. I'm not too savvy with PHP and my lecture notes are doing nothing but confusing the hell out of me.

I have a rough idea about GET methods and POST, but how would I do the button coding? The 'show order' button should return a page of the customers' order. I have tried to read plenty of tutorials but this has sadly become my last resort and really hope someone can help me out with proper explanation.

If I'm not clear with anything here please do let me know I will explain it a little more, and no, I'm not asking for anybody to do the code for me, I just need a head start so i know how to start coding it.

My HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
      <title>Task 1 </title>
      <style>


      </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <center> <h1>Legendary Ice Creams </h1> </center>
  <h4>Customer Information</h4>
  <form action"task1.php" method = GET>
  Customer Name: <input type="text" name="Your Name" title="Please enter your name   here"  placeholder="Your name here"><br>
  Table number:  <select name="Table number">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  </select><br>
  Regular Customer: <input type="checkbox" name="regularcustomer"
  value="regularcustomer"><br>

<h4> Orders </h4>

 <label for = "mulList[]"> Select one or more items</label>
              <select id = "mulList[]" name = "mList[]" size = "4" multiple
              = "true">
                <option value = "First">First</option>
                  <option value = "Second">Second</option>
                  <option value = "Third">Third</option>
                  <option value = "Fourth">Fourth</option>
              </select><br>


 Select Coffee: <input type="radio" name="coffee">Latte</input>
                          <input type="radio"
                          name="coffee">Cappacino</input>
                          <input type="radio" name="coffee">Flat Half
                          De-Caf</input><br>

 <button type="button" name="showOrder" action="task1.php">Show Order</input>
 <button type="button" name="cancelOrder" action="task1.php">Cancel Order</button>

 </form>
```

Comment: You need to wrap the code in `<form>` tags. Without that, none of the input will be submitted to the server. And the [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) tag does not have an `action` attribute (only `formaction`).

Comment: @AmalMurali Thanks for your reply. What do you mean by wrap the code with <form> tags?

Comment: Some resources for PHP/HTML/JS for you: the w3schools PHP form handling tutorial at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp and the php.net one at http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php ... Both have quite a bit of documentation should your notes not answer some of your basic questions :)

Comment: No, please don't suggest http://w3schools.com. It's a terrible source of information. See http://w3fools.com for why.

Comment: @AmalMurali as long as that page is correct, why should there be any problem with suggesting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your form tag is wrong, the `=` is missing and the method should be enclosed in quotes too, like this:

```
<form action="task1.php" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Now your actual problem: To give something to another php file, you need to name the HTML element with the `name` attribute. Then you can call it in this php file with `$_GET` or `$_POST`, depending in what you specified in the `form` tag. So to access your information, in my case just the name, this would be necessary:

```
$name = $_GET['Your Name'];
```

Then you can use it however you want. You can also use an easy loop to get all necessary information, the keys will be preserved and the values filtered with `filter_var`:

```
foreach($_GET as $k => $v) {
    $getvars[$k] = filter_var($v);
}
```

I hope this covers your actual question, you seemed pretty lost to me, so i tried to explain it as easy as possible.^^

A little sample of an easy form with html/php:

htmlform.html

```
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
<body>
<form action="phpfile.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="fname">
    <input type="text" name="lname">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

phpfile.php

```
<?php
    $fname = filter_var($_GET['fname']);
    $lname = filter_var($_GET['lname']);

    echo "Your name is ".$fname." ".$lname;
?>
```

Comment: First part makes sense to me. Thank you.
But as to the second 'foreach' part I'm sorry but that did not register well at all haha. I think I'll stick with the basics for now until I'm more confident.

So, does the submit button in the html code automatically look for the php file as soon as it's clicked and then the code in the php file will be executed? Meaning I don't actually have to do any code in the php file itself to make the button know what file to look for?

Comment: I tried to do it. The Show Order button is not loading anything. Just sticks to the same page.

Comment: The Submit button always submits the form in which he is placed and send it to the php file you specified in the `action` attribute. And its not only a button. Its `<button type="submit">`. ;)

Comment: @user2959072 i edited a small form as an example, maybe it helps you understanding how the system works. :)

Comment: Oh yes, that makes sense. I had <button type="button"> lol. 
What does the '.' do that you have included before and after $fname and before $lname?

Comment: You mean the dots? They are used for string concatenation. You can either use `"Your name is ".$fname` or `"Your name is $fname"`. I usually prefer the version with dots, its better for the performance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "=" missing.

```
<form action"task1.php" method = GET>
```

should be

```
<form action="task1.php" method = "GET">
```

right?

Then you should be able to print the selected content in your

**task1.php**

```
<?php
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($_GET);
 echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Correct?

Comment: Thanks. Missed that one.

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not use space inside the `name` attribute of your HTML elements. Either replace it an underscore or club the two words together.

Inside your `task1.php`, you can capture the user input by using the `$_POST` super variable. So $_POST['Your_Name'] will contain whatever the user typed inside the `Customer Name` textbox. You can have information about all the keys that you need by using:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST); // replace this with $_GET if using method="GET" in your form tag
echo '</pre>';
```

in your `task1.php` page. I suggest you start by doing this and take it from there.

Also, remove the `action` attribute from your `<button>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use space between names like `Your Name` in customer name better use `Your_Name` or anything you want
second add `=` between `action` and `"task1.php"`

and in

```
<button type="button" name="showOrder" action="task1.php">Show Order</input>
```

type will be `submit` i.e

```
<button type="submit" name="showOrder" action="task1.php">Show Order</input>
```

**task1.php**

```
if(!empty($_GET)){
echo "Customer Name:".$_GET['name'];//Printing Name
...
}
```

Comment: Somehow missed this reply! Thank you! makes alot more sense now that it actually does something when I click the button haha.